# Subtract two numpy arrays containing datetime.time

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

In my script I get two huge np arrays that I want to subtract. The first numpy array `start_per_day` with the times the working day started and a second numpy array `end_per_day`. 
However I get the below error. Couldn't figure it out, appreciate any help.

**Edit:** below is a minimal reproducible example where the arrays are artificially were created by me

**Edit2:** Since I was asked multiple Times about the origina of my two datetime.time numpy arrays, I extract them from pandas groupby with min and max see code below

```
print(one_employe)
start_per_day = one_employe.groupby('Date')['Time'].min()
end_per_day = one_employe.groupby('Date')['Time'].max()
print(end_per_day.values)
print(start_per_day.values)
```

The output of the 3 print commands

> ```
>    ID            Datetime        Date      Time
> 0  13 2020-03-02 09:43:00  2020-03-02  09:43:00
> 3  13 2020-03-02 18:22:00  2020-03-02  18:22:00
> 5  13 2020-03-03 09:51:00  2020-03-03  09:51:00
> 8  13 2020-03-03 18:28:00  2020-03-03  18:28:00
> [datetime.time(18, 22) datetime.time(18, 28)]
> [datetime.time(9, 43) datetime.time(9, 51)]
> ```

**Original Post - Code:**

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
start_per_day = np.array([datetime.time(9, 43),datetime.time(9, 51)])
end_per_day = np.array([datetime.time(18,22),datetime.time(18,29)])

#Attemps that didnt work:
np.datetime64(end_per_day) - np.datetime64(start_per_day)
datetime.timedelta( end_per_day, start_per_day)
end_per_day - start_per_day
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

Comment: `datetime.time` objects don't implement addition or subtraction.  `start_per_day` is an array of `time` objects; it can only do the math that those objects implement, if any.

Comment: `numpy` can do fast math with `np.datetime64` dtypes, but not `datetime` objects.

Comment: It might help to know how you created those arrays.  Object dtype arrays often are inferior to lists.  Were those `time` objects handed to you by some other code?  You couldn't have read them directly from a file.

Comment: @hpaulj I edited the origina of the `datetime.time` np array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `datetime.timedelta` instead of `datetime.time`:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

start_per_day = np.array([datetime.timedelta(hours=9, minutes=43), datetime.timedelta(hours=9, minutes=51)])
end_per_day = np.array([datetime.timedelta(hours=18, minutes=22), datetime.timedelta(hours=18, minutes=29)])

delta_per_day = end_per_day - start_per_day

print(delta_per_day[0])
print(delta_per_day[1])
```

I was looking for a way for subtracting `datetime.time` objects but I couldn't find any.

---

Conversion testing (without a loop):

```
t1 = np.array([datetime.time(9, 43),datetime.time(9, 51)])
t2 = np.array([datetime.time(18, 22), datetime.time(18, 29)])

start_per_day = np.array([datetime.timedelta(hours=t1[0].hour, minutes=t1[0].minute), datetime.timedelta(hours=t1[1].hour, minutes=t1[1].minute)])
end_per_day = np.array([datetime.timedelta(hours=t2[0].hour, minutes=t2[0].minute), datetime.timedelta(hours=t2[1].hour, minutes=t2[1].minute)])

delta_per_day = end_per_day - start_per_day

print(delta_per_day[0])
print(delta_per_day[1])
```

---

Converting array of `datetime.time` objects to array of `datetime.timedelta` objects:

```
def time_to_delat(t):
    """Convert datetime.time object with hour and minute to datetime.timedelta object"""
    dt = datetime.timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute)
    return dt

start_per_day = np.array([datetime.time(9, 43),datetime.time(9, 51)])
end_per_day = np.array([datetime.time(18, 22), datetime.time(18, 29)])

# Convert array of datetime.time objects to array of datetime.timedelta objects
start_per_day_dt = np.array([time_to_delat(x) for x in start_per_day])
end_per_day_dt = np.array([time_to_delat(x) for x in end_per_day])

delta_per_day = end_per_day_dt - start_per_day_dt

print(delta_per_day[0])
print(delta_per_day[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check if there is a way to convert the np array to timedelta. However the above is just a minimal reproducable example. In the full script I dont create these arrays by hand. I will edit the OP to clarify

Comment: I added a conversion testing